# Python3 and BeautifulSoup to scrape addresses from google returns "[]" rather than the address

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is my python3 script:

```
    import bs4, requests
    def getCompAddress(https://www.google.com/search):
    res = requests.get(https://www.google.com/search)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('#rhs_block.LrzXr')
    print(elems)
```

...the url for `getCompAddress` is just google's search result. So for the [Crossings at Five Forks](https://www.google.com/search?q=crossings%20at%20five%20forks&oq=crossings%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2j69i60l2j69i61.2744j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), google displays address and phone information on the right. I just want to scrape the address, whose CSS path I've copied into `soup.select`.

But when I run this script, all that prints out is "`[]`" ... rather than an address. What am I missing here? Does google prevent this sort of scraping? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should check res.text variable for the html response of the site.

You should usually use this way to debug BeautifulSoup scrapers as the result might be different from the expected one because of many different reasons (such as javascript support or captcha checks)

Also, as far as i know, google has a captcha check to prevent robots (and make people use their paid api)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VPN to harvest results. I came across this project on github which allows you to do just that by hosting a VPN from inside of a Docker container https://github.com/pry0cc/ProxyDock

Google does actually prevent search result harvesting. They block tor, and publicly available VPN proxies.